Aspire AddOracleDatabaseDbContext set optionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior
I have a readonly database connection which I turn off Tracking.
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
 {
     base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
     optionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
 }

When I change my code from
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseOracle(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ReadOnlyConnection")));

to
builder.AddOracleDatabaseDbContext<MyContext>("ReadOnlyConnection");

When I run my code and hit the database I get:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'OnConfiguring' cannot be used to
modify DbContextOptions when DbContext pooling is enabled.

If I remove the override OnConfiguring it works. Is it possible to set UseQueryTrackingBehavior else where?

AddOracleDatabaseDbContext registers context pool via AddDbContextPool call, which by design:

you need to pass all the context options to your DbContextFactory, rather than configuring them in OnConfiguring

One of the options would be to pass the configureDbContextOptions action:
builder.AddOracleDatabaseDbContext<MyContext>("ReadOnlyConnection",
    configureDbContextOptions: o => o.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking));

And remove/"fix" the OnConfiguring override:
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }
    
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
        }
    }
}

Another option would be to try registering the context "manually" and follow it with the EnrichOracleDatabaseDbContext call as suggested in the docs.
